# Testing: collisions in sha1, sha256 of all phone numbers

Tags: python

I need to know whether I will have birthday collisions when hashing domestic (10 digits) and international (15 digits) phone numbers.

"Shouldn't have" != will not have

I thought I would quickly run some python to SHA1 each n in the space using redis SADD response = 0 to tell me if a collisions occurred.

Now a 10^n space seems small, but then when you map the pairwise comparisons, we are in O(10^n) space and that is a bad place to be computationally.

1. Do I need a perfect hash?  I want these phone numbers to be unrecoverable so SHA256 has merits, but value^2 + value + salt or some such may be fine.  I don't care about bit length of field, within reason.  I will be doing joins though...
2. Any proof that anyone knows about that there are zero collisions in sequential set of numbers for a particular hash?  Not probability of collision, but proof.

Thanks much!

Edited to reflect that it is smaller than n! and is indeed (10^n)(10^n-1)/2 so O(10^n) thanks DSM

Comment: Where did you get that factorial? Even if you checked for pairwise comparisons, there would "only" be n^2 pairs for n phone numbers. (10^15)^2 is still a huge number, parly because 10^15 is a huge number, but neither is anywhere close to (10^15)!. However, you don't need all pairs to find collisions.

Comment: pairwise comparisons would be (n choose 2)

Comment: 10^10 = 10^10, (10^10 choose 2)= 5 x 10^19, is O(n!)

Comment: @ToddCurry: (N choose 2) *is* O(N^2).  (I'll use N for the number of phone numbers.)  5e19 is nowhere near N!; (10^10)! ~ 2.3257962056730833e+95657055186.  In any case, you wouldn't need to to do pairwise comparisons to find collisions anyway (think of set membership tests.)

Comment: Once you can calculate all the hashes, the hash is not unrecoverable anymore.

Comment: DSM, you are partially correct it is not O(N^2), but it is also not O(n!) -- it is in fact O(10^n) as it is precisely 1/2*10^n*10^n-1.  I've edited above in my question

Comment: bereal, that is true ONLY if you know I hashed phone numbers.  I won't be sending you the IP of the server :)

Comment: If you can do that, I can do that as well. And the numbers between 0 and 10^10 are all in public domain.

Comment: Using a Bloom filter with 10bits/element you'll end up with about 11.6GB for the 10 digit case. So that might fit in your memory. You'll get a 1% false positive probability so hopefully you'll be able to prove there's no collisions there. The 15 digit case is huge though.

Comment: ToddCurry: partially correct, what now?  The only one who said anything about O(n!) was you; both @delnan and I rejected that.

Comment: DSM - are you trying to be helpful or just bored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is to have a unique key for each phone number, you can simply use symmetric cryptography such as AES. Use the phone number as the key, this guarantees that no other phone number will produce the same cipher.

Generation:  "Original text" ---- encrypting with key=phone_number----> "9&*&Y*(&GG(O&GG(B)H)*H"

Verification: "9&*&Y*(&GG(O&GG(B)H)*H" ---- decrypting with key=phone_number----> "Original text"

Comment: Brilliant, TK -- just what I was looking for.  No one will know my private key, therefore Beral (above) can't hack.   Thanks so much!

Comment: @ToddCurry Just a note: "unrecoverable" and "unrecoverable without knowing a secret" are slightly different.

Answer (score 2):

You anticipated that people will tell you you "probably" won't have a collision, but still it's worth clarifying what that means. The odds of finding a duplicate SHA2 are so low, that it's more likely a solar ray or a manufacturing defect will randomly flip a bit in your CPU. There's always a small chance that your program will go crazy, so it doesn't really make sense to code around probabilities that are even less likely than that.

You could argue that malicious input could make it more likely to hit a collision. But as of March 2015 no collision for SHA1 or SHA2 has ever been found with any input, and when one is found it will be big news.

@tk.'s suggestion to use AES is clever, so if that works for you, great. But if you run into problems -- for example, if you find yourself with a key longer than 32 bytes -- there's nothing wrong with falling back to SHA2.